# How to store form logic in machine readable format?

Tags: python, database, logic

Our objective is to create an application where users specify input in online forms. There is a lot of form logic involved. This means that the user flow is determined by the answer they provide in their forms. For instance, when a user selects "yes" at question 3, go to question 6 whereas if the user selects "no" go to question 4.

Of course a python module with various cases (if, elif etc.) would work (in a convoluted way) but it feels like there might be a better way.

For instance, TypeForm support logic, like below:

[image]

We are searching for a solution that will work nicely with a front-end UI (e.g. based on Node.JS/React/Vue etc.)

We already tried TypeForm, Jotform but have struggled to find good programmer friendly solutions.

Are you familiar with (Python) tools we can leverage to achieve the above?

Comment: If you want to use the UI of Typeform for your respondents but create forms in a programmer friendly way maybe you can create Typeforms with our Create API: https://developer.typeform.com/create/

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me that you would benefit from a *finite state machine* (FSM).

You can define an initial state (first question), and then depending on the action of the user (answer), transition to another state (question). Apart from transitioning to other states, actions of users can also produce outputs (make the machine do something before or during the transition to another state).

FSMs are a very popular and relatively simple framework in engineering.

Background reading on FSM:

1. A good and quick read on FSM: https://isaaccomputerscience.org/concepts/dsa_toc_fsm?examBoard=all&stage=all
2. A very brief introduction: https://brilliant.org/wiki/finite-state-machines/

As for Python:

1. This package appears pretty simple and intuitive https://github.com/pytransitions/transitions
2. Another good package: https://python-statemachine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
3. A tutorial covering how you could implement your own FSM (it's not that hard, give it a look) https://www.python-course.eu/finite_state_machine.php